# How do I find the partial sum of the Maclaurin series for $e^x$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion, power-series, exponential-function

In one of the problems I am trying to solve, it basically narrowed down to finding the sum $$\sum^{n=c}_{n=0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$ which is the partial sum of the Maclaurin series for $e^x$.

Wolfram | Alpha gave the output
$$\frac{e^x\Gamma(c+1,x)}{\Gamma(c+1)}$$
But I am unsure how to derive this. All my usual summation evaluation tricks are not helpful and I am clueless.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: This is a case where you basically go from answer to question rather than vice versa.  Start with the [incomplete Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) and its recurrence relation.

Comment: Please don't use images where possible. This is particularly simple to render: just use `\Gamma` to produce $\Gamma$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got to doing this and got some help from aops xd

Anyhow derive the result by starting with the incomplete gamma function

$$e^x\Gamma(c+1, x) = \int_x^\infty \underbrace{t^c}_u \cdot \underbrace{e^{x-t}}_v \text{ d}t$$
Repeatedly integrating by parts and noting that $c$ is finite and an integer gives us
\begin{align*}
e^x\Gamma(c+1, x) &= x^c + c\cdot x^{c-1} + c(c-1)\cdot x^{c-2} + \cdots + c(c-1)\cdots 2\cdot x^1 + c! \cdot x^0 \\
&= c! \cdot \sum_{n=0}^c \frac{x^n}{n!} \\
\implies \frac{e^x\Gamma(c+1, x)}{c!} &= \sum_{n=0}^c \frac{x^n}{n!}
\end{align*}

The series starting from $0$ spits out terms in reverse order compared to the integration by parts.

Using the gamma function gives the desired result
$$\frac{e^x\Gamma(c+1, x)}{\Gamma(c+1)} = \sum_{n=0}^c \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align*}\sum^{c}_{n=0}\frac{x^n}{n!}&=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{x^n}{n!}-\sum^{\infty}_{n=c+1}\frac{x^n}{n!}\\
&=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{x^n}{n!}-\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{x^{n+c+1}}{(n+c+1)!}\\
&=e^x-e^x\left(1-\frac{\Gamma(c+1,x)}{\Gamma(c+1)}\right) \\
&=e^x\frac{\Gamma(c+1,x)}{\Gamma(c+1)}
\end{align*}$$
Here $\Gamma(a,x)$ is the [Incomplete gamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html).

Comment: Thanks for this too :)